# Distorted sound with a Lexicon Alpha USB sound card

Tags: 14.04, sound, audacity, noise

The issue is, whenever I open a program which uses audio in some way (skype, audacity etc.) the sound of my audio player (any, I've tried at least 3 of them) turns glitchy and distorted. To resolve this, I have to go to sound settings and change from 'analog' output to 'digital' or vice-versa, any kind of change solves the problem. The thing is, it happens all the time.

I have installed pulseaudio volume manager. I'm using lexicon alpha USB device. I've even disabled internal soundcard in bios AND blacklisted it, since for some reason Ubuntu was still recognizing it. No matter what combination of analog/digital input or output I choose, the problem persists.

Comment: FWIW, I think this is a fault with the Alpha - I have exactly the same problem, but on Windows :(